# Only fire an event once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

How do I control only firing an event once?

Actually, a quick Google appears to allude to the fact that `.one` helps..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`one` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/), which will subscribe to only the first occurrence of an event.
For example:

```
$('something').one('click', function(e) {
    alert('You will only see this once.');
});
```

Comment: OK, awesome, just wondering, what is the 'e' between your parentheses?

Also, does this function require two parameters?  1 for what you want to only run once, and the other for the function?

Comment: `e` is the event formal parameter for the callback.  In this case it is unused.  The two parameters are the event type and function.

Comment: Awesome!  That is really helpful, what is the difference between this and .bind?  Is it that it doesn't need to be unbound by something like .unbind?

Comment: The `one` method can take three parameters; see the documentation.  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: As stated in the documentation, calling the `one` method is equivalent to calling `bind`, then calling `unbind` in the handler.

Answer (score 74):

Use [`once`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener) if you don't need to support Internet Explorer:

```
element.addEventListener(event, func, { once: true });
```

Otherwise use this:

```
function addEventListenerOnce(target, type, listener, addOptions, removeOptions) {
    target.addEventListener(type, function fn(event) {
        target.removeEventListener(type, fn, removeOptions);
        listener.apply(this, arguments);
    }, addOptions);
}

addEventListenerOnce(document.getElementById("myelement"), "click", function (event) {
    alert("You'll only see this once!");
});
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
- http://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/
- https://www.webreflection.co.uk/blog/2016/04/17/new-dom4-standards

Comment: Beautiful method, i never thought about using named functions like that. See my answer for a slightly improved version preserving `this` and passing all arguments.

Comment: @Shikyo I've added `this`

Answer (score 6):

Just use proper option in your addEventListener method call:

```
element.addEventListener(event, func, { once: true })
```

Comment: Not supported by IE.

Answer (score 5):

Same as rofrol's answer, just another form:

```
    function addEventListenerOnce(element, event, fn) {
        var func = function () {
            element.removeEventListener(event, func);
            fn();
        };
        element.addEventListener(event, func);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly improved version of rofrol's anwser:

```
function addEventListenerOnce(target, type, listener) {
    target.addEventListener(type, function fn() {
        target.removeEventListener(type, fn);
        listener.apply(this, arguments);
    });
}
```

By using apply all arguments are passed and the `this` works as expected.

Comment: you should not use that hacks anymore, there is a simple way to do that element.addEventListener(event, func, { once: true }), as @kapitalny pointed out

Comment: It is indeed much nicer but IE is a ... https://caniuse.com/#search=once

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can do this:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function handleClick(e) {
    window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);

    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the options for add/remove event listener:

```
function addEventListenerOnce(target, type, listener, optionsOrUseCaptureForAdd, optionsOrUseCaptureForRemove) {
    const f = event => {
        target.removeEventListener(type, f, optionsOrUseCaptureForRemove);
        listener(event);
    }
    target.addEventListener(type, f, optionsOrUseCaptureForAdd);
}
```