# Call addEventListener resize once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a resize function that fires when the browser is resized, on desktop it will only fire once when the page first loads. But if the user is on a mobile browser like Safari or Chrome, it will fire multiple times, because when the the user starts to scroll the browser address bar and bottom navigation will shrink or disappear causing the viewports to change and then firing the resize event.

So, is there a way to wrap the function or `addEventListener` and only let it call the function once, or atleast once depending on the screen size?

I posted part of my JavaScript below, so you can see the `newSize()` function and resize event listener.

```js
function newSize() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if (w > h * (16 / 9)) {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", { attr: { width: w, height: w * ratio } });
    } else {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
            attr: {
                width: h / ratio,
                height: h
            }
        });
    }
    var data = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        x: w / 2 - data.width / 2
    });
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        y: h / 2 - data.height / 2
    });
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);

newSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", newSize);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [force javascript EventListener to execute once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878805/force-javascript-eventlistener-to-execute-once)

Comment: Keep track of the previous width and only run the rest of your script if the new width is different. Or if you truly only want your code to load once when the page is loaded, you should probably be using `document.onload` instead. Any time the user adjusts their screen on desktop it will fire the `resize` event again also, so don't expect that to only fire once if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a track of the old width whenever resize is fired, and execute your methods only if the width has changed (So in case of address bar hiding, you can skip the methods):

```
var oldWidth = 0;

function newSize() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;

  if(oldWidth !== w){ // Check if width has changed
    oldWidth = w;

    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if (w > h * (16 / 9)) {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", { attr: { width: w, height: w * ratio } });
    } else {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
            attr: {
                width: h / ratio,
                height: h
            }
        });
    }
    var data = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        x: w / 2 - data.width / 2
    });
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        y: h / 2 - data.height / 2
    });
  } 
}
```

Comment: When I get home I’ll try this out along with the other suggestion above and I’ll report back!

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct, because it works just like you said. I just ran into another issue though, once the user starts scrolling the image doesnt resize (which is what i wanted) but now there is like a "blank space" that you can see where the image would have originally resized to. So i either have to find a solution with CSS or something or decide if I should just keep the resize event like i had and let the page jump when the user scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

1. addEventListener accept options as a third argument. And one of options — once. So you can do:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", newSize, { once: true });
```

But IE does not support this option.

2. You can manually remove listener after it was called:

```js
const handleResize = () => {
  newSize()
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
}
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
```

3. If you want do *some staff* only if *some other staff* was changed, you can check it in your listener. For examle:

```js
const currentWidth = window.innerWidth
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  if (window.innerWidth === currentWidth) {
    return
  }

  newSize()
  currentWidth = window.innerWidth
})
```

In that case if only height has been changed, newSize will not be called.