# MOUSEOVER: How to start a function and let it play until the end without start it over and over?

Tags: javascript

I want to start a function when I over mouse an ID `#show-details`.
But I need it to start only one until it ends, not to start over and over again ...

With my code below It starts when I `mouseover` it but starts over and over even if it doesn't finish.
I need some help :)

```
function showDetails() {

  var details = document.getElementById('show-details');

  details.addEventListener('mouseover', initDetailsLetters);

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [force javascript EventListener to execute once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878805/force-javascript-eventlistener-to-execute-once)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a flag, if the flag doesnt exist then create it and start over, if it does exist then dont run the code

Answer (score 0):

Try a callback function, I have found this example to help you: [Proper way to wait for one function to finish before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing)

This looks similar to your problem