# JS hover link call function, but only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html page, with many links.

When a link is hovered over, it calls a function `dothis()` that changes the contents of a div on the page, but I only want it to run the function once for each link no matter how many times it is hovered over.

For example, if the user hovers over a particular link, moves the mouse away and hovers again, it will not load the function again (each link has this 1 hover limit, so the user could hover over link A, then link B can still run the function when hovered over (but only once for each link)).

I have jquery loaded if that makes things easier.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only fire an event once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)  --- Happy New Year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
.one()
```

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed **at most once per element**.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) on [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
$("#elementID").mouseenter(function(e){
$(this).unbind(mouseenter);
});
```

or [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#elementID").one("mouseenter",function(){
//do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

When a user hovers over a link, a function will check an internal variable. If it's null, the function will set the internal variable so that it doesn't call the dothis() function more than once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hover Once</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <a href="#" onmouseover="onHover(this)">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="onHover(this)">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="onHover(this)">Link 3</a>

        <script>

            function onHover(element) {

                if(element.alreadyHovered == null) {
                    console.log("call dothis()");
                    element.alreadyHovered = true;
                }

            }

            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find alreadyHovered in the jquery docs...do I need to set it as a variable in the script outside the onHover function?

Comment: Javascript is a interpreted, prototypical language; you can just plaster new variables on to objects without any complications. The variable alreadyHovered could be named anything, assuming it isn't a keyword already used by an HTML element. Edit: And even then, you can usually still do it.