# Allow users to add location on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a classified website. I need to allow users to mark their location on google map. I just found this and working nicely.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

The problem is this allows to add any number of marks. But I need only one marker at all. Any solution?

Comment: Sure, when adding another marker, have it remove the others. simple.

Comment: for calling an event only once look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once) but I think Kevin is right from a users experience perspective you should have it overwrite the old marker

Answer (score 0):

```
This is an exemple of function :

function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        //if marker already was created change positon
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        //create a marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
    }
}

call :

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
        placeMarker(evt.latLng);
    });
```