# Bootstrap modal not working on loop scenarios

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create generalised method for ajax in my javascript and bootstrap modal is not working as expected.

HTML :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="consult_modal_v2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div style="background-color: #dc3d3e;color: #fff;height:85px !important;;" class="modal-header">
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <h4 id="message_v2" style="text-align:center;margin-top: 10px;"></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="con_close1_v2" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:3%;margin-bottom:2%;">

                    <div class="col-md-3" id="con_uname_v2" style="margin-top:11px">Admin Username</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" id="con_sect_name_v2" class="form-control"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="con_pass_v2" style="margin-top:11px">Admin Password</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9"><input type="password" id="con_sect_pass_v2" class="form-control"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div style="border:none;" class="modal-footer" >
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="con_close_v2" style="margin-top:3%;">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="con_sect_ok_v2" style="margin-right:2%;margin-top:3%;">Override</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="con_upd_sect_ok_v2" style="display:none;margin-right:2%;margin-top:3%;">Override</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

Executed as

```
generalised_ajax('post_url',
    {
        'sub_id': sub_id,
        'status': status,
        '_token': csrf_token
    }, "POST", function () {
        console.log('success placing apt');
    }, {},
    function () {
        console.log('apt cancelled');
    }, {});

function generalised_ajax(url, data, type, post_success, post_success_params, post_cancel, post_cancel_params) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: type,
        headers: {Accept: "application/json"},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            post_success(post_success_params);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.responseJSON.type === "confirmation") {
                responseProcess = xhr.responseJSON;
                generalised_confirm(responseProcess.message, {
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    type: type,
                    post_success: post_success,
                    post_success_params: post_success_params,
                    post_cancel: post_cancel,
                    post_cancel_params: post_cancel_params
                }, responseProcess.config_name);
            } else if(xhr.responseJSON.type === "admin_auth"){
                generalised_authentication(responseProcess.message, {
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    type: type,
                    post_success: post_success,
                    post_success_params: post_success_params,
                    post_cancel: post_cancel,
                    post_cancel_params: post_cancel_params
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function generalised_confirm(message, data, config_name) {
    var r = confirm(message);
    if (r === true) {
        data.data[config_name] = true;
        generalised_ajax(data.url, data.data, data.type, data.post_success, data.post_success_params, data.post_cancel, data.post_cancel_params);
    } else {
        data.post_cancel(data.post_cancel_params);
    }
}

var modelX = $("#consult_modal_v2");
function generalised_authentication(message, data){
    var uname = $("#con_sect_name_v2");
    var pass = $("#con_sect_pass_v2");
    $("#message_v2").val(message);
    modelX.modal('toggle');
    $("#con_sect_ok_v2").click(function(event){
        modelX.modal('toggle');
        data.data['a_uname'] = uname.val();
        data.data['a_pswd'] = pass.val();
        uname.val('');
        pass.val('');
        generalised_ajax(data.url, data.data, data.type, data.post_success, data.post_success_params, data.post_cancel, data.post_cancel_params);
    });
    $("#con_close_v2").click(function(event){
        modelX.modal('toggle');
        data.post_cancel(data.post_cancel_params);
    });
}
```

Expected scenarios:

1. Sent ajax
2. Server responded with admin_auth error
3. Open modal
4. Input admin creds (wrong ones)
5. Close modal
6. Sent ajax
7. Server responded with admin_auth error
8. Repeat from stage 3

How it's working right now

1. Sent ajax
2. Server responded with admin_auth error
3. Open modal
4. Input admin creds (wrong ones)
5. Close modal
6. Sent ajax

Now server responded with same ajax as Point 2. But modal won't open again.
It is working fine with javascripts confirmation popup.

Update:

After I removed fade class from modal, it started appearing everytime. But now it sends double of ajax of previous attempt.
Like for first time once, second time twice, third time 4 times, 4th time 8 times and so on.

Comment: **Bootstrap modal not working on loop scenarios** The first thing that came in my mind was is the ID dynamic? changing? because if the modall is between a loop the modals will all have same ID

Comment: No, modal id stays `consult_modal_v2`, it's same auth modal, if auth fails once, it should reopen on ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the reason of this behaviour but
changing

```
$("#con_sect_ok_v2").click(function(event){
        modelX.modal('toggle');
        data.data['a_uname'] = uname.val();
        data.data['a_pswd'] = pass.val();
        uname.val('');
        pass.val('');
        generalised_ajax(data.url, data.data, data.type, data.post_success, data.post_success_params, data.post_cancel, data.post_cancel_params);
    });
```

to

```
$("#con_sect_ok_v2").one('click',function(event){
        modelX.modal('toggle');
        data.data['a_uname'] = uname.val();
        data.data['a_pswd'] = pass.val();
        uname.val('');
        pass.val('');
        generalised_ajax(data.url, data.data, data.type, data.post_success, data.post_success_params, data.post_cancel, data.post_cancel_params);
    });
```

solved it.

Credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393694/2598994