# Javascript/Adobe DTM: Tracking Checkbox Clicks Only Once

Tags: javascript, dom-events, adobe, event-tracking

First, as usual, sorry if this answer exists but I searched and couldn't quite find the answer for which I am looking.

I'm trying to track an action on an input checkbox only **once**, that is if I have a list of checkboxes I want to only track if user clicked on it **once**, so even if they deselect a chackbox they've checked only the first click is tracked.

I know there's a way to check if a checkbox has been clicked in JS via `querySelector().input` type call, but I'm lost as to how to bring that full circle to only have tracking event fire only once regardless of how many times the user toggles it.

Consider the following markup:

```html
  <li class="js-form-item form-item form-item__item form-item--checkbox__item">
    <span class="checkbox"> 
      <input view_id="explore" display_id="explore_main" data-drupal-selector="edit-category-title-app" type="checkbox" id="edit-category-title-app" name="category[title_app]" value="title_app" class="form-checkbox form-item__textfield">
        <label for="edit-category-title-app" class="checkbox__label">
          <span class="checkbox__faux"></span><span class="form-item__label">App</span>
        </label>
     </span>
</li>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Vanilla JS only, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only fire an event once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

Comment: Maybe not since the krux of my question is how to implement in DTM rather than page script.

Answer (score -1):

Attach an event listener and remove it when it is triggered.

```
function addEventListenerOnce(target, type, listener) {
    target.addEventListener(type, function fn(event) {
        target.removeEventListener(type, fn);
        listener(event);
    });
}

addEventListenerOnce(document.getElementById("edit-category-title-app"), "change", function (event) {
    alert("You'll only see this once!");

    // DTM call here
});
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

Comment: If you found an identical question (from which your copied your answer) then you should instead flag it duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, but I would dispute that this is a duplicate as the real krux of my question is how to implement this in DTM, a tag management system, instead of the page script.

Comment: I think the key is to attach the event handler client side, and fire a custom event which is picked up by DTM. I don't think there is anything you can do exclusively in DTM itself to achieve this