# Add text only once after input on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some text on submit after the form's input value changes. I only want it to add it once but my code adds it every time the input is clicked.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/okass/pen/KbvvjL

```
 <form>
  <input id="input-1" type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
    var txt = $(':input[type="submit"]');
    txt.val("sorry for the wait")
    txt.after("text to add")
    e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only fire an event once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

Comment: Thanks Chris but I'd looked at .one() but couldn't see how to pair it with .submit()

Comment: Maybe the best way to do this is using a div or span after the button. Using this method you can show the div/span and change his value when is necessary. Using after you have some limitations and the text are not inside a specific tag or something.

Comment: `$("form").one("submit", function(e) { ...` This is also explained at the very start of the docs: `A string containing one or more JavaScript event types, such as "click" or "submit," or custom event names.`

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: But `.one()` will restrict you to submit only once, you will not be able to submit second time!!!

Comment: @Mamun The second submission will not be intercepted by the event handler and instead triggers the browser's standard form submission. My guess is this is what OP wants. I also suspect this may be an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a variable by setting true/false, if the value is *true* then add text otherwise not:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = true;
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    var txt = $(':input[type="submit"]');
    txt.val("sorry for the wait")
    if(flag){
      txt.after("text to add");
      flag = false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="input-1" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```