# How to trigger click event on element only once while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, triggers, click

While listening to scrolling I want to trigger click event on an element only once. This event should scroll to an element. My code sofar:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  window.onscroll = slideMenu;
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
    const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

    if (scrolledPx > 100) {
      const link = document.getElementById('2');          
      link.click();
      link.removeEventListener('click'); // ????
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that while I meet the condition scrolledPx > 100 - it keeps triggerring the link.click() event. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only fire an event once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

Answer (score 1):

Define variable and check it conditinal

```
let disableClick = false
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  window.onscroll = slideMenu;
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
    const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

    if (scrolledPx > 100 && !disableClick) {          
      const link = document.getElementById('2');          
      link.click();
      disableClick = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great. How would it be possible to reset the disable click to false once the scrolling down is changed to scrolling up and the  if (scrolledPx > 100 ) condition is reached?

Comment: If i understand true you can reset it inside `if (scrolledPx < 100 && disableClick)` this condition

Answer (score 1):

Use helper boolean variable:

```
let clicked = false;    
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      window.onscroll = slideMenu;
      if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
        const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

        if (scrolledPx > 100) {
          if(!clicked) {
             const link = document.getElementById('2');
             link.click();
             clicked = true;
             link.removeEventListener('click'); // ????
          }          

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the link was previously clicked, or remove the scroll event listener. I think that latter is a better solution as scroll event listeners fire quite frequently, and if you only need it once, might as well not have the extra overhead.

```
// Method 1
var didClick = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  window.onscroll = slideMenu;
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
    const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

    if (scrolledPx > 100 && didClick === false) {
      const link = document.getElementById('2');          
      link.click();
      didClick = true;
    }
  }
}  

// Method 2

function myScrollHandler(){
 window.onscroll = slideMenu; // You may want to move this elsewhere
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop) {
    const scrolledPx = (window.scrollY - elementTarget.offsetTop);

    if (scrolledPx > 100 && didClick === false) {
      const link = document.getElementById('2');          
      link.click();
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', myScrollHandler); // ????
   }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', myScrollHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a global variable you may consider to add a new boolean property to your element:

```
if (scrolledPx > 10) {
    const link = document.getElementById('2');
    // stopclik  is undefined at beginning
    if (link.stopclik == undefined) {
        link.click();
        link.stopclik = true;
        // set it to true.....
    }
}
```

Comment: All the solutions work great. Exactly what I asked for. However, I found little problem with the solution. While scrolling down the click event is triggered but if I scroll further the scroll to element that I used the click for stops working and it doesn't finish scrolling to the element. How would it be possible to prevent it? Maybe call the click event after some time or pixels scrolled?

Comment: @Roman If i understand true you can reset: delete document.getElementById('2').stopclik ;