# How can I break or return from addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I don't know how to break or return from addEventListener

Here I get "Undefined label 'testfunc'" error

```
testfunc:
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("TEST")
        break testfunc
    })
```

Here I get "TEST" everytime i click but I want it only to console.log("TEST") only once

```
function testfunc(){
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("TEST")
        return
    })
}
```

Comment: _"but I want it only to console.log("TEST") only once"_ - None of your attempts would do that (if they would work)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener can take an options object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only fire an event once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393686/only-fire-an-event-once)

Comment: `addEventListener` is not a loop. You need to call `removeEventListener` to stop it from being called again.

Comment: @Ivar good spot.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can create some variable and put there flag (true/false), for example:

```js
let isClicked = false;

function testfunc(){
    test.addEventListener("click", function(){
      if (isClicked) return;
        console.log("TEST")
       isClicked = true
    })
}
```

Comment: @LukaZmaj Sure it works, but it makes more sense to stop the event completely from firing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an anonymous function as the event handler and you want to remove the listener from within that function, you'll face a challenge. Since the function is anonymous, you don't have a direct reference to it for removal. One way to overcome this is by using a variable to store a reference to the function before passing it to `addEventListener`. Here's an example:

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

// Define the event handler as an anonymous function
var handleClick = function() {
  console.log('Button clicked!');
  
  // Remove the event listener using the stored reference
  myButton.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
};

// Add the event listener
myButton.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

In this example, `handleClick` is initially assigned the anonymous function. This allows you to reference the same function when adding and removing the event listener.

Remember, the key here is to have a reference to the same function when calling `removeEventListener`. If you need to remove the listener under different conditions, make sure you're calling `removeEventListener` with the same reference to the function that was used to add the listener.

This approach makes the anonymous function more versatile, as you can now add and remove it as an event handler at different times.