# How can I make a button clickable only one time?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button that gets disabled after one click/is just clickable one time...
I couldnt find anything about it.

Comment: Hi can you kindly display your attempt at what have you have tried?

Comment: You can remove an event listener or use a boolean flag and an `if` and/or add the `disabled` property. Which you choose depends on your use case, particular needs and existing code, which hasn't been described or shared yet (please [edit] to add details!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling and enabling a html input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button)

Answer (score 3):

Add a click event listener to the button which disables it.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.disabled = true;
})
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Good idea disabling it, but it'd also be good to remove the event listener. I think this combined with [a once listener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3393686/7665043) would do it.

Comment: @l3l_aze that is quite interesting, but won't be necessary here, since the `click` event won't fire for a disabled button.